# Why is self used with init but not colour

Tags: swift, self

I am taking an online class on swift and an example was shown. Why is self used with the init method call but not on colour?

```
class Car {

    var colour = "Black"
    var numberOfSeats = 5
    var typeOfCar : CarType = .Coupe

    init() {

    }

    convenience init (customerChosenColour : String) {
        self.init()
        colour = customerChosenColour
    }
}
```

Comment: `self` is implicitly used on `colour`, you only have to type it out if the parameter name is the same as the property, e.g `self.colour = colour`

Answer (score 1):

An `init()` runs when someone makes a new instance of that class like this:

`var newInstanceOfCar = Car()`

A `convenience init` allows you to create other initializers for certain use cases, like when there is a `customerChosenColour` that needs to be specified. It makes things more convenient in those cases.

The reason why `self` is used, is because when you create `convenience init`, you still need to call the "main" `init`, which is a property of `self`.

---

You can use `self` on colour, but it isn't necessary. You would use `self.colour`, if `colour` was ambiguous, like in this example:

```
class Car {

    var colour = "Black"
    var numberOfSeats = 5
    var typeOfCar : CarType = .Coupe

    init() {

    }

    convenience init (colour : String) {
        self.init()
        self.colour = colour
    }
}
```

Notice how `colour` is a property of `Car`, but is also the name of the parameter for the `convenience init`. It would be confusing to write `colour = colour`.

So we use `self` to say that we want the variable in our class, `self.colour`, to be equal to the value of the parameter, `colour`.

Comment: So if you could use self on color but you can just leave it out, can you not leave it out when calling self.init()

Comment: @AndrewBreeze-Stringfellow You have to use self if you have a parameter and a property of the same name, like in my example, because it isn’t clear what `colour` you’re referring to. Initializers aren’t exactly like functions, so you can’t just call `init()` it’s own, you __always__ have to use `self` or `super` when you refer to initializers.

Answer (score 0):

As you wonder why `self.` cannot be omitted in `self.init()`, you can think of `self.init()` as whole is a special keyword just for convenience initializer. Same as `super.init()` as whole is a special keyword just for designated initializer. And `Car.init()`aka `Car()` is for creating a new instance. Calling `init()` itself without any receiver is not a valid call ever. So you can treat function call `init()` as nonexistence, `self.init()` is one keyword, `super.init()` is another keyword.

`init()` is not a member function, it is the initializer, some special code which will be run when creating new instances of that class. Don't treat initializers as regular member functions. They don't have the `func` keyword in front. They don't have the property of member functions. You can call member function on an instance but you cannot call initializer on an instance (`Car().init()` is not valid). `self.init()` dose NOT mean calling a function named `init()` from `self`.

```
class Foo
{
    init(){}

    func foo(){}

    func bar()
    {
        self.foo()  //valid. regular member function call
        self.init() //invalid. init() is not a member function of the instance
    }
}
```

Don't think `self.init()` like calling regular method from the same class, where `self.` can be omitted, but rather treat the whole thing as a special keyword that means "initialize this object with the designated initializer first".